# For loop doesn't loop values of an object - applies same handler to each element

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I've written a function that is meant to provide an easy way of creating right-click (context) menus. Fine, but the functions you pass into it as click handlers don't get applied to the right menu items.

When I call the function, I pass it the click event and an object literal containing menu item names and their handler functions, like this:

```
context.menu(e,{
    "Hello": function() {
        alert("Hi");
    },
    "World": function() {
        alert("Hello world!");
    },
});
```

Supposedly, the object literal is looped through in a `for` loop and each handler function is applied to the corresponding menu item. However, it seems that the first handler function passed in is getting applied to all the menu items.

The function goes like this:

```
this.menu = function(e,options) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var x = e.clientX;
    var y = e.clientY;
    var id = math.floor(math.random()*8192);
    id = "menu-"+id;
    var menu = "<div class='menu-wrapper'></div>";
    menu = $(menu);
    menu.attr("id",id);
    var i = 0;
    for(var key in options) {
        var option = $("<span class='menu-item' id='menu-item-"+i+"'>"+key+"</span>");
        var fn = options[key];
        option.appendTo(menu);
        option.on("click",function() {
            // $(this).css("background","yellow"); - just a test, not needed any more
            fn.call();
        });
        i++;
    }
    menu.appendTo("body");
    menu.css({
        top: y,
        left: x,
    });
    $(document).click(function() {
        $("#"+id).remove();
    });
    $("#"+id).click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
}
```

How do I change this so that the handlers get applied in the right places?

[Live JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ArtOfCode/bU63z/1/)

**UPDATE:**

I've tried adding code (using `typeof(options[key]);`so it checks the type of the function you pass in but still no luck. `console.log` also gives me the right values so I don't know why it's not looping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common pitfall here. JS doesn't have block scope - your `fn` variable is being rewritten each iteration. Try wrapping it in a closure.

```
this.menu = function(e,options) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var x = e.clientX;
    var y = e.clientY;
    var id = math.floor(math.random()*8192);
    id = "menu-"+id;
    var menu = "<div class='menu-wrapper'></div>";
    menu = $(menu);
    menu.attr("id",id);
    var i = 0;
    for(var key in options) {
        (function(key){ // start closure
            var option = $("<span class='menu-item' id='menu-item-"+i+"'>"+key+"</span>");
            var fn = options[key];
            option.appendTo(menu);
            option.on("click",function() {
                // $(this).css("background","yellow"); - just a test, not needed any more
                fn.call();
            });
        })(key); // end closure
        i++;
    }
    menu.appendTo("body");
    menu.css({
        top: y,
        left: x,
    });
    $(document).click(function() {
        $("#"+id).remove();
    });
    $("#"+id).click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
}
```

Comment: Hmmm... would have thought it needed to be rewritten each iteration, but hey. It works perfectly, many thanks.