# IE8 Cannot add properties to JavaScript object returned by window

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, host-object

I just came across this odd issue in IE8 and I cannot seem to find any more details about it. Naturally, if I create a JavaScript object, however I do it, I can simply add properties by dynamically defining them:

```
var rect = {};
rect.x = 200;
```

Great. Well in IE8 (and I'm not sure what other IE's), if I call a method like this:

```
var span = document.getElementById('my-span');
var rect = span.getBoundingClientRect();
rect.x = Math.round( rect.left );
```

then I get the IE error "Object does not support this property or method." This of course does not happen in the first case I mentioned where I personally defined my own object in javascript. Now the easiest workaround will be to do this:

```
var clientRect = span.getBoundingClientRect();
var rect = { top: clientRect.top, left: clientRect.left, right: clientRect.right, bottom: clientRect.bottom };
rect.x = Math.round( rect.left );
```

That's no problem. But what I am wondering is why won't IE8 let me dynamically add fields/properties/attributes (I am not sure of the correct JS terminology) to this object returned by the `getBoundingClientRect()` method? Is there another (correct) way to add properties? Does this happen for all objects returned by methods from the `window` object? Is this documented? Or is it a bug? (In which case I'll take the workaround and move on).

Comment: First question: is it read-only?

Comment: And the answer is yes.

Comment: @Bergi I think he means that the result of `getBoundingClientRect()` seems to be read-only

Comment: All results (incl. objects) returned by DOM methods are read-only. This is not documented, but implied by common sense.

Comment: @hindmost Not all of them, for example, think about result of `getElementById(..)` being read-only ... Also, the return value of `gBCR()` [doesn't seem to be read-only](http://jsfiddle.net/jwL5ucsa/) in FF or Chrome.

Comment: @Teemu: I tested mine in Chrome 38, it did come back read-only.

Comment: @ArtOfCode I've version 37, the above linked fiddle works fine in it.

Comment: @Teemu Hmm. Perhaps Google changed something between versions?

Comment: I will have to say that I was not aware of read-only objects in JavaScript. Per @Teemu's comment, I use `document.getElementById(..)` and I modify the values of DOM elements all day. This must be where my common sense breaks down. If the DOM method `getElementById` returns objects that are not read-only, is this the only method that does such? If not, then which DOM methods return objects that are read-only and which DOM methods do not?

Comment: If `gBCR()` is read-only whether not, is not mentioned at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536433%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getBoundingClientRect#Browser_compatibility) article says: `"In IE8 ... additional properties ... cannot be added onto these TextRectangle objects."`

Comment: Might be a question for another SE site @MichaelPlautz. As far as I know, the methods that return **elements** are read-write (e.g. `getElementById`, `getElementsByTagName` (and `NS` versions), etc)

Comment: @MichaelPlautz Maybe `gEBI()` was a poor example, it returns a reference rather than an object.

Comment: @Teemu according to MDN it returns an Object, not a reference (if you create var rect2 = span.getBoundingClientRect(); rect === rect2 // false) and in other browsers and IE8+ you can happily add properties.  And, as you point out, it is a documented issue.

Comment: @CoolBlue I wrote `getElementById()` returns a reference : ).

Comment: @Teemu Ooops, my apologies!

Comment: @Teemu Sorry, I'd used wrong terminology. I meant by "read-only" that object returned by DOM method cannot be modified in the manner the OP used in his example, i.e. adding properties/attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is in the fact that the result of `getBoundingClientRect()` is read-only. Thus, you cannot add properties to it. You can however read them into your own object (as your workaround does). There is a slightly more succinct way to do it:

```
var span = document.getElementById("span");
var rect = span.getBoundingClientRect();
var myRect = {};
for(var key in rect) {
    myRect[key] = rect[key];
}
```

This results in myRect having all the properties of the `getBoundingClientRect()` result, but they are now read-write, and you can add `myRect.x` to them.

EDIT: FF and Chrome <= 37 appear to return `getBoundingClientRect()` read-write by default

Comment: Why the IIFE? Wouldn't `myRect[key] = rect[key];` just do the same?

Comment: I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24465806/for-loop-doesnt-loop-values-of-an-object-applies-same-handler-to-each-element) about that a while ago. Statements like `myRect[key] = rect[key];` didn't work in my `for` loops - though I haven't tried it in this context.

Comment: Well, it definitely will work without IIFE here. Your case was different because it tried to read a value in an event handler, and the value was changed before the handler was called.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, it is *only* an issue for IE8 and earlier as pointed out by @Teemu.

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window,'rect')
// Object { configurable=false, enumerable=true, writable=true, ...}
```

As a work-around, why not wrap it in an object...

```
    var rect = {
        clntRect: span.getBoundingClientRect(),
        x: function () { return Math.round(this.clntRect.left) },
        y: function () { return Math.round(this.clntRect.top) }
    }
```

or...

```
    var rect = {
        span: span,
        clntRect: function () { return this.span.getBoundingClientRect() },
        x: function () { return Math.round(this.clntRect().left) },
        y: function () { return Math.round(this.clntRect().top) }
    }
```